# Adding an x number of new lines to the end of a file Python

Tags: python, addition, mask, lines

I have multiple files that I am looping over. If an individual file doesn't have a certain length then I want to mask the lines in that file so that it isn't used but so that the shape remains the same for certain calculations I will need to do in the future. So far this is the code that I have:

```
pattern = "C:\Users\Name\Folder\july\mid_2014-07-2?-00.csv"
bad_files=[]
for filename in glob.iglob(patterm):
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
    if num_lines!=144:
        s = 144 - num_lines
        bad_files.append(filename)
print bad_files
```

This so far returns a list of all of the files that don't have 144 lines in them. What I want to do is if the file doesn't have 144 lines in it (for example say it has 127 lines) then I want to add 's' number of blank lines to the end of the file to make it have 144 lines. Then I want to mask all of the lines in the file so that the shape is maintained for what I want to do with it but those lines won't be used in certain calculations. Is there a way to add a statement in this loop that adds 's' number of blank lines to the end of the file and also a statement that masks every line in the bad file? Is there an easier way to achieve what I want to do that I should consider?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I can't help but wonder if it's as simple as `filename.write('\n' * s)`.

Comment: @MattCremeens it works. Just fired up the interpreter and tested it.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMurphy. Also, not sure what is meant by "...masks every line in the bad file?"

Comment: Are you already assured that no file has more than a gross of lines?

Comment: Thanks for answering the first (majority) part of my question to add an 's' number of lines! What I mean by mask is that I would like to see if I could use numpy.ma mask function to hide the values in the bad files. From what I understand this allows me to keep everything the same shape while not using the values for calculations. I am sure there are no files that have more than 144 lines.

Comment: Yes, you can use masked arrays to continue processing around missing values.  Before we put this to rest, can you describe just what you're doing?  **numpy.ma** ignores invalid entries for computations -- such as row/column sums.  If you're trying to invert a matrix with haphazardly missing entries, you're going to have troubles.

Comment: I am planning to ultimately use this large dataset of model data for a multiple linear regression so the large array of observations (that I already have) and the large array of model data has to be the same length. So I want to mask the bad model data like described above. That way it doesn't use the files that have missing data in them but still maintains the same shape so that the regression function will work. I haven't done anything with the masking code yet so I am open to suggestions. I apologize if this still doesn't make sense, I am new to the masking idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't really need the list of file names for processing, then this can collapse to:

```
for filename in glob.iglob(pattern):
    with open(filename, 'r+a') as fd:
        for num_lines, line in enumerate(fd): pass
        # num_lines is now one *less* that the actual line count.
        fd.write('\n' * max(0, 144 - num_lines))
```

Note that you cannot do **filename.write()** because the file name is a string.  **write** works on a file descriptor.